# How to compare each dataframe row to each point of a tuple and assign the closest point's index to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine the following dataset:

```
   X  Y
0  2  4
1  5  6
2  3  4
```

Now, imagine the following tuple of points: ((2,4), (6,5), (1,14))

How can I find the closest point to each row and assign the index of the point to a new column?

For example, since the closest point to the first row is the point with index 0, the first row would become:

```
   X  Y  Closest_Point
0  2  4  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `scipy` , the logic here is broadcast

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
ary = distance.cdist(df.values, np.array(l), metric='euclidean')
ary.argmin(1)
Out[326]: array([0, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Perhaps my example was bad. What happens in case the dataset has way more points than the tuple (e.g. a 50000 x 2 dataset)?

Comment: @lifetea try it it should be same

Comment: I did try it and I got an error that operands could not be broadcast together with shapes.

Comment: It's 4 AM and you cannot imagine how helpful your advice was. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would for sure use Numpy to make both the tuple and the dataset into numpy arrays.

For the examples you gave:

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.array([[2,4],[5,6],[3,4]])
points = np.array([[2,4],[6,5],[1,14]])
dataset_indexed = []

for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
    temp= (((dataset[i,0]-points[0,0])**2 +(dataset[i,1]-points[0,1])**2)**(1/2))
    index=0
    for n in range(points.shape[0]):
        print(((dataset[i,0]-points[n,0])**2 +(dataset[i,1]-points[n,1])**2)**(1/2))
        if(((dataset[i,0]-points[n,0])**2 +(dataset[i,1]-points[n,1])**2)**(1/2)<=temp):
            temp= ((dataset[i,0]-points[n,0])**2 +(dataset[i,1]-points[n,1])**2)**(1/2)
            index = n
            
    dataset_indexed.append([dataset[i,0],dataset[i,1],index])
```